# Numpy from an array, for each element create a matrix N*M with all values set as the element without for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, pytorch

I have a numpy array like np.array([1, 2, 3])

Without using for loops but just use numpy or pytorch methods, i want a matrix with dimension len(array) * N * M composed by matrices N*M that the first matrix is composed by all ones, the second only by two values and the third only by 3 values.

For istance

```
N = 4 M = 3
[[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]], 
  [[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2]], 
  [[3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3]]]
```

I tried different methods to achive this matrix like unsqueeze and repeat but i wasn't able to find a solution, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
np.ones((len(a),M,N)) * a[:,None,None]
```

Or without multiplication:

```
np.full((len(a),M,N), a[:,None,None])
```

Output:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.]]])
```

**Note** the shape here and given in your expected output is `len(a) * M * N`, not `len(a) * N * M`. Swap `M,N` in `np.ones` if needed.

Comment: In PyTorch similar to it would be `torch.ones((len(a),M,N)) * a[:,None,None]`

Answer (score 1):

In PyTorch you can use [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand)

```
a_t = torch.from_numpy(a)

a_t[:,None,None].expand(len(a_t), M, N)
tensor([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Another way would be using [`repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat)

```
a_t[:,None,None].repeat(1, M, N)
```

this similar to numpy `tile` -  `np.tile(a[:,None,None], (1,M,N))`